# Understanding package management systems for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, package-management

I have a low-end laptop and am looking to install a lightweight `linux` distribution on it, but I have certain requirements regarding package management systems, since I will be contributing to a web development project.

I'm looking at Elementary OS which is a `Debian` distro (like `ubuntu`), and it seems I can use the `apt-get` package management system, which is really important for me.

That made me curious. I was looking at `Solus OS` (which I know isn't super lightweight), but it is also a `Debian` distribution.

However, the package management system on `Solus` is `eopkg`, and I'm wondering why I can't use `apt-get`.

Since the `Debian` package manager is `dpkg` and `apt-get` is derived from that, why can't we get `apt-get` on `Solus OS`? Or can we?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Solus isn't based on Debian (or any other "parent" distro).  Their model is a tightly integrated and limited scope custom system using their own package management (which is incompatible with deb and rpm), and other tools.  That integration is the fundamental thing Solus is designed to offer.  If you want something different, it doesn't make sense to use Solus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is it still true then that if Debian was the parent distro, it would be able to use the `apt-get` package manager. Since don't all packages use the `.deb` file extension? Apologies if I'm making little sense.

Comment: If it was a derivative of Debian, it would likely use deb packages.  The main reason to use a "parent" distro as a starting point is to build on it and utilize its development resources (and its stocked and tested repository).  The Solus project was started with the purpose of developing a new model from scratch.  They discuss some of that here: https://solus-project.com/why-solus/.  BTW, deb isn't the only system.  The RedHat family uses rpm, and there are a few others.  The advantage of using deb or rpm is that third party software is often available in those.